# Make VirtualizingStackPanel not clean up already loaded items

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, compact-framework

Is there any way to make the `VirtualizingStackPanel` in Windows Phone only clean up / re-virtualize items if they have not yet loaded?

To explain a bit more what I want: When I load a large list of items using a heavy `ItemTemplate` with images I would use a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to avoid clogging up the UI and wait until all the elements have been drawn to the screen.

This is good if you scroll *down* nice and slow in the list. But the problem is when you scroll up again viewing items that has already loaded once. Since `VirtualizingStackPanel` now has cleaned up those elements they need to be loaded again.

What I would like is for those items that are already loaded not to be cleaned up.

I don't know how they do it, but the IMDb app seems to be using something like this for their *top 250* and *bottom 100* movies list. I also noticed that they don't load images while you are scrolling so it doesn't clog up the UI unless you are standing still in the list.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What question are you actualy asking?  What is your real goal here? If performance of scrolling down is fine, why are you unhappy with the scrolling up?  Or are you really asking how to defer the loading of heavier components in the item template until scrolling is unchanged for short period?  Be clear about what it is that you are really after.

Comment: I think I made myself pretty clear: VirtualizingStackPanel needs to reload items that has already been loaded once when they are moved out of view. This is a bad thing, and I don't want that. What I want is for the items that has already been created once not be unloaded and then loaded again when they come into view the second time, i.e. I want them to not being cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a warning, my advice comes from a WPF background not Silverlight nor WP7. But in my experience they are not that different.

First i would check if changing the [VirtualizationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) helps. Setting it to Recycling might already increase your performance.

Otherwise its going to be a bit more challenging to do what you want. You would need to create your own VirtualizingPanel, and set it up to manage creating items dynamically. You find a good set of articles [here](http://rhnatiuk.wordpress.com/2006/12/13/implementing-a-virtualized-panel-in-wpf/). But instead of clearing the "once visible but now virtualized items again", you just keep them so you got in the end all items realized.
I know its a bit vague, i have code here which i use for our custom ToolBar if necessary i can post some of it to explain a way how to do it. (Again without guarantee that it works for WP7 aswell).

Best regards

Comment: This looks really interesting! Even though it's for WPF the concepts are the same. I'll read through the blog posts and mark as accepted if it works :)